# How does thread::detach() work in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I wrote the following code and am unable to understand why doesn't it prints out all the no's(i.e. 0 to -99) in threadFunc() as it does with main() thread.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<string>
#include<mutex>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;

mutex mu;

void threadFunc(){
    for(int i=0;i>-100;i--){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30)); /*delay for 30ms*/
    mu.lock();
    cout<<"Thread:  "<<i<<endl;
    mu.unlock();
    }
}

main(){

    thread t1(threadFunc);   


    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    mu.lock();
    cout<<"Main:  "<<i<<endl;
    mu.unlock();    
    }


    cout<<"End of Main"<<endl;  

    t1.detach();   
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
Main: 0  
Main: 1  
.  
.  
.  
Main: 99  
End of Main.  
Thread: -1
```

Comment: FYI, your loop in `threadFunc` starts at `i = 0` and runs if `i >= 100` (I assume `>-` is a typo for `>=`) which is **never** true.

Comment: @JamesAdkison, why? The loop is correct and I do not see any typos there.

Comment: @SergeyA The loop in `main` is fine but not the one in `threadFunc`.

Comment: @JamesAdkison, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: I think loop is correct. I'm doing i-- (decrementing i every time by 1).

Comment: @JamesAdkison What is wrong with `i > -100`? That is, looping as long as `i` is greater than minus one hundred?

Comment: @SergeyA I see, I was reading it as `>= 100` (which I stated) but it's `>   -100`). My mistake.

Comment: @Angew Thanks, I had just realized that on my own and leaving a comment when you left your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Process terminates when `main()` exits, and all threads are killed. You observe this behavior in your program.

Detach basically says that from now on, you can't `join` this thread. But if you can't `join` it, you can't make your `main()` to wait until it completes (unless you use other synchronization primitives) - and thus it is happily exiting.

This is why I strongly discourage everybody from using detached threads, they are very hard to do properly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Can you please explain something about how detach() works.

Comment: @AbdulAtique, detach basically says that from now on, you can't `join` this thread. But if you can't join it, you can't make your `main()` to wait until it completes - and this is exactly what is happening in your case. The proper way is to `join` the thread before exiting `main()`.

Comment: @SergeyA : I couldn't have said that better myself.

Comment: Recommendation, @SergeyA : Pick that comment up and paste it, with some tweaking, into the answer. Makes for a stronger answer.

Comment: @user4581301, recommendation dully followed :)

Comment: @SergeyA, Thanks for your answer, I was trying to figure out why all my `cout`s don't work in detached thread when `main` completes, but didn't find the answer for a long, now things are clear! I thought that threads created in main continue to live in background, now I know that all threads created by the program are killed when main completes.

Comment: @VadimSorochan glad it was useful!

Answer (score 6):

The `detach` function prevents an exception from being thrown when the `thread` object goes out of scope. Usually, you would want to call `join` but if you don't want to block the execution you need to call `detach`. However, you probably need to use another synchronization mechanism to make sure everything is fine if the `thread` is still running when `main` is ready to exit. See the following **contrived example**.

#### Example Code

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool finished = false;

void threadFunc()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        std:: cout << "Thread:  " << (0 - i) << "\n";
    }

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
    finished = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::thread t1(threadFunc);
        t1.detach(); // Call `detach` to prevent blocking this thread

    } // Need to call `join` or `detach` before `thread` goes out of scope

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        std::cout << "Main:  " << i << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "End of Main\n";

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
    cv.wait(lock, [&finished]() { return finished; });

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
Main:  0
Main:  1
Main:  2
Main:  3
Main:  4
End of Main
Thread:  0
Thread:  -1
Thread:  -2
Thread:  -3
Thread:  -4
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/qp53Y3)

Again, the above is a **contrived example** and in your case you could more easily use `join` instead of `detach` before allowing `main` to return.